# Checking if variable of type QDialog is created/assigned or not

Tags: qt

I have a header file like following:

```
testDialog* test; //Here testDialog is a QDialog type
```

This is my .cpp file:

```
test = new testDialog(m_dialog);
```

I want to check if the dialog is created/assigned to `test` before executing it.

So I did the following in my cpp file:

```
void testApp::init() {
if (somethingelse) {
    test = new testDialog(m_dialog);
    mFlag = true;
}
}
```

Here I am overriding the exec function:

```
int testApp::exec()
{
    if (mFlag) {
        test->show();
        test->activateWindow();
        mFlag = false;
    }
    return testApp::exec();
}
```

This works. But I was wondering if it is possible without using the flag. Something like directly check if a new dialog type is created/assigned in `test`. Can anyone suggest anything? Thanks.

Comment: It is much better and safe to use `QPointer` wrapper. It will be automatically nulled, when object will be destroyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check: if (test == Q_NULLPTR)

In your .h file create the following steps: testDialog *test = Q_NULLPTR;

```
void testApp::init() {
    if (test == Q_NULLPTR) {
        test = new testDialog(m_dialog);
        //mFlag = true;
    }
}

int testApp::exec()
{
    if (test) {
        test->show();
        test->activateWindow();
        //mFlag = false;
    } else { //if you want
        test = new testDialog(m_dialog);
        this->exec(); // or test->show(); test->activeWindow();
    }

    return testApp::exec();
}

void testApp::deleteTest() {
    delete this->test;
    this->test = Q_NULLPTR;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply test `if ( test != NULL && test->isVisible() )`.

This will be evaluated to `true` if dialog was created and is now visible (note that it may return false if you called `show()` but the app did not show it yet).

As commented, make sure you set `test` to NULL upon class initialization.

Comment: You forgot to tell that `testDialog* test` variable should be initialized to a null pointer value, i.e. `testDialog* test = nullptr;` otherwise your proposal will not work.

Comment: The dialog is not visible there yet. I was just assigning/creating the test variable of type testDialog. I just tested it, it doesn't execute the ´if´ part as I haven't called `show()` anywhere before.